# What is the proper way to activate @PostConstruct via CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor by Java configuration?

Tags: spring, spring-annotations

I'm using Spring 4 with SpringBoot and Spring-Web with Java configuration.

To have my [`@PostConstruct`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-postconstruct-and-predestroy-annotations) annotated methods executed by Spring at launch, it is necessary to register `CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` with the context, otherwise `@PostConstruct` is ignored.

In a XML-based Spring configuration, the docs say to use (under the beans element)

```
<context:annotation-config/>
```

I have also seen an example where registration is done on an individual bean basis, like so:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
```

I wish to avoid this if possible. My project does not include any XML file, and none is generated for me in my build folder.

Currently, my solution is to annotate my class with [`@ComponentScan`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-scanning-autodetection), which I believe causes Spring to detect and register `@Component`s and `@Bean`s. 
Somehow, this causes `CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` to be invoked, although I have no idea why, but it solves my problem!

(This class has one `@Autowired` property, which is null at startup - hence the need to do the initialization via `@PostConstruct`)

But again, my question, what is the *proper* way to achieve this using Java configuration? Thank you!

Comment: You need to tell the context that you want to use annotation, either manually by registerig all `BeanPostProcessor`s (not recommended) or by using `<context:annotation-config />` (which is already implied when using `<context:component-scan />`. Or by using an `ApplicationContext` implementation that by default uses annotations like the `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`. There is no single proper way to do it al the mentioned ways are valid.

Comment: The fact that you have a `@Autowired` property that is null shouldn't be the case as spring should autowire. Generally this implies that you haven't told the context you want to use annotation .

Comment: @M. Deinum Thank you. To clarify, the `@Autowired` property is injected but the value is not yet available at the time the static/instance constructors are running, hence the use of @PostConstruct. 

The context is aware of ***some*** annotations, (perhaps via `@SpringBootApplication`, `@Configuration` and `@Component` which I do use), but docs state that @PostConstruct is not one of them and so  some way to enlist `CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` is needed. 

I would like that way to be consistent with Java configuration, (without XML).

Comment: The `@PostConstruct` is already handled if you have enabled annotation, which is by default the case if you use java based config.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [InitializingBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean.html) as an alternate solution.

Simply extend this interface and override [afterPropertiesSet](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean.html#afterPropertiesSet--) method that will be called after setting all the properties of the bean just like post construct.

For example:

```
@Component
public class MyBean implements InitializingBean 
{
    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet()
    {
        // do whatever you want to do here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. Here's what I did:
`code`
@Component
public class Example implements InitializingBean {
 @Autowired
 private MyThing myThing;

 @Override
 public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
  // make use of myThing here, after it has been injected.
 }
}
`code`

@Braj I'll leave the question unanswered for the moment to gather more knowledge. Will close it in a few days.

Comment: The Spring documentation discourages to use this interface because it unnecessarily couples the code to Spring. [Initialization callbacks](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-lifecycle-initializingbean)

Comment: @rvheddeg I agree with you. In another way we can use `@PostContruct` annotation or `init-method`. [Example](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-postconstruct-and-predestroy-example/)

Answer (score 0):

This is *not* an answer to my question as posed, but another alternative solution.

I could have implemented the [Lifecycle](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/Lifecycle.html) interface and done my initialization in the `start()` method. At the time I was stumped what to return for the `isRunning()` method, although hindsight says `return true` would have been good enough as its lifetime is application-long. Any suggestions on that point would be welcome.

```
public interface Lifecycle {

  void start();

  void stop();

  boolean isRunning();

}
```

Other alternatives may be inferred from [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.0.M3/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lifecycle-combined-effects), namely

```
<beans default-init-method="init">
```

which, I gather, allows *every* `@Bean` to have its optional init() method called. (I have not tried it).

Still, I'm hoping for an answer to my question that uses Java Configuration.